# String compare with batch file

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables, delayedvariableexpansion

A very simple batch file. I'm trying to search for file extensions that are not .txt. There will be one .txt, but the rest will be like .txt_20190607.

```
for %%I in (\\01mtsdv130\Myapp\Log\*.*) do (
    set var1=%%~xI
    echo %var1
    if %var1%==".txt" ( 
       echo Matches
    ) else ( 
        echo does not match 
    )

)
```

I have files in that folder both .txt and those with the extra date info in the extension. What do I have wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in the code.

The first one is that `%`-based expansion of normal variables is rather "static", in that it happens the first time code is parsed/executed and is fixed since then. That means that in iterations of the loop after the first, the result of `%var1%` will *not* change. You'd have to use `!var1!` (along with setting `EnableDelayedExpansion`) to get the behaviour you want.

An easier alternative is to get rid of `var1` altogether and just use `%%~xI`.

The other problem is that CMD treats quotes (almost) as any other character. Most notably, the strings `a` and `"a"` are not considered equal. Therefore, the `if` should look like this:

```
if "%%~xI"==".txt" (
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Angew. This worked correctly if "%~xI"==".txt" ( , but if "%var1%"==".txt" ( did not, the comparison became "if "" ==".txt".

Comment: Quite the opposite, in batch files the `FOR` variables must be used with double percents `%%` dereferencing or otherwise. So the OP did that part right. The problem with code is `1.` Assigning and using a variable in the same code block by percent variable expansion `%var%`, which should use delayed expansion `!var!` if variable access  can't be avoided and `2.`  Mixing quoted and unquoted strings in comparison as you mentioned in your answer. So `if "%%~xI"==".txt"` would be correct.

Comment: @sst Right you are, thanks for the correction. I was certain it was `%%` at declaration only, but apparently my memory tricked me (it's been some time since last I had to do this stuff).